# Preparing layout to print multiple images on page using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, layouts

I want to print multiple images on a layout page with legends.

All images are the same size and same georeferencing.

How should I prepare it?

Comment: Data Driven Pages: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000006000000

Comment: @Mapperz, I don't think DDP is the correct solution here.  The question is about multiple images on a single page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The secret is to create multiple data frames.  The image below shows six data frames, each with the same base imagery though different layers above that.  Try the following steps:

1. Set the page layout at File -> Page and Print Setup...
2. Click on the default data frame in the layout so that it turns light
   blue
3. Adjust the size of the first data frame to your specifications.  For
   more control, right click on the data frame -> Data Frame Properties
   -> Size and Position.  Here you can set the exact height and width.
4. Add your base layers to this dataframe and choose the appropriate
   zoom levels.
5. Now you right click on the data frame and copy and paste a new data
   frame into the page layout.
6. Arrange however many you would like on the page.
7. To set the legend, select a data frame you would like to create a
   legend for and choose Insert -> Legend...
8. Follow the legend wizard instructions
9. If you want to duplicate the same legend, simply copy and paste like
   you did for the dataframes.  Otherwise, if each dataframe has unique
   data, select each data frame and create a legend for each.

[image]